# onEdit function

Tags: google-apps-script

in google apps script, how can I automatically run a script when I change the background color of a cell?
When I change the background color of a cell, the spreasheet is automatically saved and it says also when last edit was made, but if I try to use this event on an onEdit function to run a script, it doesn't recognize the event and does nothing. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

onEdit is going to fire when any cell value changes, not with any formatting changes.  You'll have to place the rules to change the bg colors in the script, assuming that the rules are based on cell values already in the sheet.

Answer (score 0):

I'm afraid you'll have to manage this using a 'trick' as there is indeed no automatic trigger for background color changes.

Just a suggestion : If your spreadsheet is not too big you could simply memorize the whole color description in a string you previously stored in script properties and, based on a timer trigger, check if something has changed.

If this solution is acceptable for you (the timer trigger and not an immediate reaction) give it a try...

Use this var for example :

```
var backGroundString = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet().getDataRange().getBackgrounds().toString()
```

and compare it to the same value stored in scriptProperties, if different, trigger your event...

I know it's a bit clunky but right now I see no other simple way to get what you want.

You could add a few conditions to make it work only at some moments or when the spreadsheet is open...